# How can I hide the caret when not in edit mode?

Tags: qt, text-editor, qgraphicsitem, qgraphicstextitem

I have a `TextItem` inheriting `QGraphicsTextItem`. I made it so that on double-click I can edit the text, and when clicking out, the text is no longer editable.

```
void TextItem::mouseDoubleClickEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent * event)
{
    setTextInteractionFlags(Qt::TextEditorInteraction);
    setFocus();

    int p = document()->documentLayout()->hitTest(event->pos(), Qt::FuzzyHit);
    QTextCursor _cursor = textCursor();
    _cursor.setPosition(p);
    setTextCursor(_cursor);
}

void TextItem::focusOutEvent(QFocusEvent *event)
{
    Q_UNUSED(event);
    setTextInteractionFlags(Qt::NoTextInteraction);
}
```

When clicking out, the text is no longer editable - but the caret is still visible.

Adding `setCursor(Qt::OpenHandCursor);` in the `focusOutEvent` (and possibly trying to remember which cursor shape to set... I don't know how yet) fixes this - makes the caret disappear - but I don't think it is the right fix.

Yet I cannot find any method in `QTextCursor` to hide the caret when no longer in edit mode - and it seems that setting `NoTextInteraction` should have done that...

What is the best way to hide the caret when not in edit mode ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added a clear selection on lost focus, since it seems that not only the caret is left but any selected text is also left selected - and it is not the behavior I wanted.

```
void TextItem::focusOutEvent(QFocusEvent *event)
{
    Q_UNUSED(event);
    setTextInteractionFlags(Qt::NoTextInteraction);

    QTextCursor _cursor = textCursor();
    _cursor.clearSelection();
    setTextCursor(_cursor);
}
```

The above clears the caret, as well as any selected text fragment.

(If anybody reading this question is looking to save selection on text fragments, but not display the caret, the option I mentioned in my question - by setting the `QCursor` - may be the best option)

Comment: You can save the selection, then clear it, then restore it :)

Answer (score 1):

You are talking of the caret - the on-screen indication of the text editing position. What you describe looks like a Qt bug.

The `setCursor` call modifies the *mouse pointer*, not the caret. It has a side effect that forces the item to synchronize the caret state with the interaction flags. The absence of such synchronization is the bug you experience.

The `QTextCursor` class doesn't represent the caret, but a position in the text document. It's a fancy iterator, completely decoupled from any visible representation of it.

The `QGraphicsTextItem` happens to maintain a caret that represents the position of its `textCursor` property. You can have other `QTextCursor` instances operating on the same document, and they won't have a visible caret associated with them - they are just iterators.

You know one workaround for the bug - via `setCursor`, but try the ones below, too:

1. An `update()` of the item after the interaction has been disabled.
2. Setting the `textCursor` to a null cursor, perhaps in combination with an `update()`.

   ```
   setTextCursor(QTextCursor());
   ```

Comment: The `update()` alone does not seem to have an effect... While Option 2 makes me unable to edit the text again on the following double-click. Perhaps I will try to store the cursor in the class... though it seems more complicated and "heavy weight" than storing the cursor shape.

Comment: Since it seems that there is a selection leftover also - I thought if I clear the selection, the caret gets cleared too. It worked !